# Does the Vimeo API allow users to upload videos to my vimeo account?

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

Does the Vimeo API allow users to upload videos to my vimeo account? If so can I do it wihtout redirecting them to the Vimeo website? So do I use the new API from vimeo or is the old just fine?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Vimeo does support uploading videos using the [advanced upload API](http://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced/upload). So you just have to build an interface which allows the user to upload a video and push that - using your favorite programming language - to your account using that API.

Comment: Thanks Knut. But do you have any idea what are the differences between the advanced upload API and their new API?

Answer (score 0):

Knut is correct - you can upload in the advanced API.  It is also supported in the new API including official client library support for Python, PHP and Node.js.

The biggest special thing you have to do is request access to upload and describe your use case.  This is done on the app edit page under the heading "Upload Access".  There'll be a link there to submit the request.